# Rails: Model method execution sequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have problem in my model. I want method to use another property of model but before using it I want another method to be executed (to make property have value). Here is an example:

```
 def medthod_one=(val)
   self.value = val
 end

 def method_two
   self.second_value = self.value / 2 #just for example
 end
```

So, in my case `self.second_value` is invalid because `self.value` is not set yet. How to change those methods execution sequence after submitting create form for this model?

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to come up with an elegant solution when you only provide foo-bar examples instead of actual code, but my guesswork tells me that you probably want something like this:

```
def som_setter=(val)
  self.value = val
end

def method_two
  return unless self.value
  # perform calculations with 'self.value'.
end
```

Comment: I was going to suggest a before_filter, but since the prerequisite is an assignment (which presumably is called from outside the class), your solution is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do this:

```
def method_one=(val)
  self.value = val
  self.second_value = val / 2
end
```

On the other hand, if `second_value` always depends on `self.value`, you can implement it as a read-only property:

```
def second_value
  self.value / 2
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not too sure I follow your question, but maybe taking a look at active record callbacks would help. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

I think you may need to reword this question.